# Deserialize JSON object into dynamic object using Json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Is it possible to return a dynamic object from a json deserialization using json.net? I would like to do something like this:

```
dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.Deserialize(json);
Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse.message);
```

Comment: Consider to generate C# class from JSON http://json2csharp.com/ and use generated class instead of dynamic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: How do you suggest stackOverflow close a question as "too old"?
It's been six years, there are valid answers and reasonable suggestions for every version of .net since then... so many that they aren't really helpful any more.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70026040/8644294

Answer (score 623, accepted):

Json.NET allows us to do this:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");

Console.WriteLine(d.number);
Console.WriteLine(d.str);
Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);
```

Output:

```
 1000
 string
 6
```

Documentation here: **[LINQ to JSON with Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm)**

See also [JObject.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) and [JArray.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm)

Comment: Note that for arrays the syntax is `JArray.Parse`.

Comment: Why do we need to use dynamic word ? i am scared never used before :D

Comment: In VB.Net you need to do `Dim d As Object = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}")`

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG You should be :) Dynamic is an anti pattern in almost every circumstances, but, every now and then, you may have a situation where it's reasonable to use it.

Comment: With Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3 (.NET 4.5.2):

  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException occurred
    HResult=-2146233088
    Message='Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'number'
    Source=Microsoft.CSharp
    StackTrace:
         at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderController.SubmitError(CError pError)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in version 10.0.1. You get the runtime binder exception. Answer is false.

Comment: Note: you should add the reference Microsoft.CSharp.dll to make use of d.number etc..

Comment: This is not/no longer (?) returning `dynamic` but a `JObject` instead (`public static JObject Parse(string json, JsonLoadSettings settings);`). Docs here:  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: @Krumelur You can still declare the type as dynamic and then access using property notation as opposed to having to access everything via indexers. The answer is correct.

Comment: 10 years later, it's still the best answer.

Answer (score 119):

As of Json.NET 4.0 Release 1, there is native dynamic support:

```
[Test]
public void DynamicDeserialization()
{
    dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"message\":\"Hi\"}");
    jsonResponse.Works = true;
    Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse.message); // Hi
    Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse.Works); // True
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResponse)); // {"message":"Hi","Works":true}
    Assert.That(jsonResponse, Is.InstanceOf<dynamic>());
    Assert.That(jsonResponse, Is.TypeOf<JObject>());
}
```

And, of course, the best way to get the current version is via NuGet.

**Updated (11/12/2014) to address comments:**

This works perfectly fine. If you inspect the type in the debugger you will see that the value is, in fact, *dynamic*. The *underlying type* is a `JObject`. If you want to control the type (like specifying `ExpandoObject`, then do so.

[image]

Comment: This never seems to work. It only returns a JObject, not a dynamic variable.

Comment: BTW, this works: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(STRING); with proper deserialization, so we do not have JObject etc.

Comment: @Gutek not sure what your issue is. Did you run the code? I added asserts to the test and added a property not in the original json. Screenshot of the debugger included.

Comment: @DavidPeden if you have JObject and you will try to bind that in Razor you will get exceptions. Question was about deserializing to dynamic object - JObject is dynamic but contains "own" types like JValue not primitive types. I can't use `@Model.Prop` name in Razor if return type is JValue.

Comment: This works, but each dynamic property is a `JValue`. Which confused me because I was working in the debugger/immediate window and wasn't seeing just `string`s. David shows this in the bottom screenshot. The `JValue` is convertible so you can just do `string m = jsonResponse.message`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, works fine for me, many thanks!

Comment: @Gutek 7 years ago, but still its the answer, thank you :)

Comment: @Alexandr ah, if only you had waited 3 more days to comment...

Answer (score 83):

If you just deserialize to dynamic you will get a JObject back.  You can get what you want by using an ExpandoObject.

```
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();    
dynamic message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonString, converter);
```

Comment: The result can be also converted to a dictionary

Comment: Exactly what I looked for! Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

I know this is old post but JsonConvert actually has a different method so it would be

```
var product = new { Name = "", Price = 0 };
var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, product);
```

Comment: That would be deserializing a json payload into an anonymous type, not a dynamic type. Anonymous types and dynamic types are different things, and I don't believe this addresses the question asked.

Comment: Is it necessary to use two variables? Why not reuse the first one in the second statement?

Answer (score 39):

Yes you can do it using the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. To do that, just simple do:

```
dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse["message"]);
```

Comment: `JsonConvert` doesn't contain a method called `Deserialize`.

Comment: it should just be DeserializeObject, but this should be the accepted answer IMO

Comment: This works :D Thank you very much, all the other answers didn't work for me. I was trying to use DeserializeObject, however instead of jsonResponse["message"] I was using the syntax I normally use with regular class objects: jsonResponse.message

Answer (score 23):

**Note:** At the time I answered this question in 2010, there was no way to deserialize without some sort of type, this allowed you to deserialize without having go define the actual class and allowed an anonymous class to be used to do the deserialization.

---

You need to have some sort of type to deserialize to. You could do something along the lines of:

```
var product = new { Name = "", Price = 0 };
dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.Deserialize(json, product.GetType());
```

My answer is based on a solution for .NET 4.0's build in JSON serializer. Link to deserialize to anonymous types is here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexghi/archive/2008/12/22/using-anonymous-types-to-deserialize-json-data.aspx

Comment: I am with you phill don't know why people down-voting this, if any one can you please.. please explain why ?

Comment: They are downvoting because the question is about deserializing without a type.

Comment: Answer was valid at the time of writing it in 2010 when there was no other solution. It was even the accepted answer for a small period of time until support came in JSON.NET.

Comment: This doesn't produce a dynamic object. This produces a JObject which you reference as a dynamic. But its still a JObject inside.

Comment: @ghostbust555 so, no different to `dynamic d = JObject.Parse...`

Answer (score 7):

If you use JSON.NET with old version which didn't JObject.

This is another simple way to make a dynamic object from JSON:
https://github.com/chsword/jdynamic

NuGet Install

```
PM> Install-Package JDynamic
```

Support using string index to access member like:

```
dynamic json = new JDynamic("{a:{a:1}}");
Assert.AreEqual(1, json["a"]["a"]);
```

Test Case

And you can use this util as following :

Get the value directly

```
dynamic json = new JDynamic("1");

//json.Value
```

2.Get the member in the json object

```
dynamic json = new JDynamic("{a:'abc'}");
//json.a is a string "abc"

dynamic json = new JDynamic("{a:3.1416}");
//json.a is 3.1416m

dynamic json = new JDynamic("{a:1}");
//json.a is integer: 1
```

3.IEnumerable

```
dynamic json = new JDynamic("[1,2,3]");
/json.Length/json.Count is 3
//And you can use json[0]/ json[2] to get the elements

dynamic json = new JDynamic("{a:[1,2,3]}");
//json.a.Length /json.a.Count is 3.
//And you can use  json.a[0]/ json.a[2] to get the elements

dynamic json = new JDynamic("[{b:1},{c:1}]");
//json.Length/json.Count is 2.
//And you can use the  json[0].b/json[1].c to get the num.
```

Other

```
dynamic json = new JDynamic("{a:{a:1} }");

//json.a.a is 1.
```

Comment: this is very nice. i was looking for something like this for a while.... fills the brief exactly

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is possible. I have been doing that all the while.

```
dynamic Obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(<your json string>);
```

It is a bit trickier for non native type. Suppose inside your Obj, there is a ClassA, and ClassB objects. They are all converted to JObject. What you need to do is:

```
ClassA ObjA = Obj.ObjA.ToObject<ClassA>();
ClassB ObjB = Obj.ObjB.ToObject<ClassB>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple and neat using generic methods.
For example:

```
TMap DeserializeAnonymous<TMap>(TMap obj, string content, JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = null)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TMap>(content, serializerOptions);
}
```

Usage:

```
string file = @"some\dir\file.json";
string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
var obj = DeserializeAnonymous(new
{
    SomeProp = "",
    SomeOtherProp = 0
}, content, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
obj.SomeProp;
etc....
```