# Deserialize JSON to anonymous object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

In C#, I have successfully serialized an anonymous object into JSON by use of code like this...

```
var obj = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String output = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

However, what I would like to be able to do later is to deserialize the JSON string back into an anonymous object.  Something like this...

```
var obj2 = serializer.Deserialize(output, object);
```

But the serializer.Deserialize() method requires a second parameter that is the type of object it will deserialize to.

I tried this...

```
var obj2 = serializer.Deserialize(output, obj.GetType());
```

But this produces an error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for type of '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

I'm not sure what this error means.

Comment: Related posts - [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3142495/465053) & [Deserializing json to anonymous object in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6671972/465053)

Comment: This has exactly what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70026040/8644294

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[**JSON.Net**](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) is a powerful library to work with JSON in .Net

There's a method [DeserializeAnonymousType](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) you can tap in to.

***Update***: Json.Net is now included with ASP.Net, however my latest favorite that I use is [**JsonFX**](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx). It's got great linq support as well, check it out.

***Update 2***: I've moved on from JsonFX, and currently use [**ServiceStack.Text**](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), it's fast!

Comment: Interesting, looks like exactly what the OP's looking for.

Comment: Update nov 11, Link is now broken

Comment: ServiceStack is not free!  For me this was important. I only found out when I reached the limits of the free version.

Comment: ServiceStack since 4.0.26 is now free, and it supports deserialization to generic `JsonObject`s

Comment: @thomasb I have no idea where you're seeing that... the license for the NuGet package, at least, has a "restricted free usage" clause (version 5.2.0).

Comment: I also wasted time checking ServiceStack on the mention of @thomasb that is free, but it's not true. As of today, [their website](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas) reports `Whilst ServiceStack v4+ is a commercially-supported product, we allow free usage of our Commercial Products in small projects and for evaluation purposes`. It's still limited until granted a "free" license,  which is unclear how to get, probably upon explicit request and evaluation of the project.

Comment: There is a free version for individuals and open source projects: https://servicestack.net/free ; I'm not sure what the status was 6 years and 2 main versions ago. Anyway, while still not as fast as ServiceStack, `System.Text.Json` has seen great performance improvements in the latest .Net Core releases : https://medium.com/@tobias.streng/net-performance-series-2-newtonsoft-vs-system-text-json-2bf43e037db0

Answer (score 55):

how about dynamics, the fastest way I see is this:

```
dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(output);

decimal Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(myObject.Amount);
string Message = myObject.Message;
```

Note: 
 You will need Newtonsoft.json.dll reference

Answer (score 16):

How about using [the DeserializeObject method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject.aspx), it does not require a specific type. This also solved [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net/2159395#2159395). The method deserializes to a `Dictionary<string, object>` containing name/value pairs.

**Update**: to clarify the error you get when doing this:

```
var obj2 = serializer.Deserialize(output, obj.GetType());
```

Given the type of `obj`, `Deserialize` will try to create a new instance of the type using a default constructor. Anonymous types in C# does not have a public parameterless constructor, and thus the operation fails.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done using the in-built JavaScriptSerializer, as follows:

```
object result = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(JSONData);
```

This will return an object[] instance, with Key-Value pairs.

Comment: This is not in .net core 2.1 unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

if you use Newtonsoft.Json you can try DeserializeAnonymousType method

```
    var obj1 = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };
    var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj1);

    // or as well
    var json= "{ \"Amount\" : 108, \"Message\" : \"Hello\" }";
   
   //Deserialization

   var definition = new { Amount = 0, Message = "" };

    //obj2 type is "anonymous"
   var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json,definition);
```

result

```
{ Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have been using the awesome [JsonFx.Net library](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx) and I've come to appreciate what it does. You can use Nuget Package Manager to install it right inside Visual Studio.

The code goes like this,

```
var reader = new JsonReader();
string input = @"{ ""first"": ""Foo"", ""last"": ""Bar"" }";
var template = new { first=String.Empty, middle=String.Empty, last=String.Empty };
var output = reader.Read(input, template);
```

As you can see you can even specify the template for Anonymous Type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JObject instead to deserialize the JSON string:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string output = "{\"Amount\" = 108, \"Message\" = \"Hello\"}";
var amount = JObject.Parse(output)["Amount"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to manually provide the type i found the easyest way is just:

```
var jsonString = JsonHelper.SerializeObject(item);
ExpandoObject obj = JsonHelper.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonString);
```