# Json Deserializer read objects to array

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, parsing, deserialization

I am writing a deserializer callback method to parse some Json response in C# silverlight.

But the problem is the response is constructed by a bunch of objects and not in an array form.

To be specific, normally when we want to parse something from a json, if that's a list of object, it will look like this in some Json visualizer:

[image: Json Array]

we can do something like:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObjType[]));
ObjType[] response = (ObjType[])jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

But now I have the Json file that the structure looks like this:

[image]

In this case I dont think I can parse it to an array since the objects are individual and not in an array structure.

A sample of the Json file is:

```
[
   {
      "Name":"Mike",
      "Gender":"male",
   },
   {
      "Name":"Lucy",
      "Gender":"Female ",
   },
   {
      "Name":"Jack",
      "Gender":"Male",
   }
]
```

So I am wondering if there is any way I can parse this kind of Json file to an array of defined object.

Comment: Could you please share sample json as text

Comment: You can use JSON.NET to deserealize json into anonmous object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904825/c-sharp-deserialize-json-to-anonymous-object

Comment: @raman Sorry I am not able to share the Json file in text since that is not public resource. But I can try to make some fake data in the same structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
string json = @"[
    {
        ""Name"":""Mike"",
        ""Gender"":""male""
    },
    {
        ""Name"":""Lucy"",
        ""Gender"":""Female ""
    },
    {
        ""Name"":""Jack"",
        ""Gender"":""Male""
    }
]";
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObjType[]));
ObjType[] response = (ObjType[])jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

-

```
[DataContract]
public class ObjType
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
    [DataMember]
    public string Gender;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
public partial class RootClass
{

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Name;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Gender;
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootClass[]));
        serializer.ReadObject(/*Input stream w/ JSON*/);

    }
```

Comment: Sample input stream: new FileStream("E:\\sample.txt", FileMode.Open)

Comment: Pay attention that in your sample there are extra commas

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T JSONDeserialize<T>(string json)
        {
            T obj = default(T);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
                obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
                ms.Close();
            }`enter code here`
            return obj;
        }
```