# Does C# have a parseJSON like jQuery?

Tags: c#, json.net

jQuery makes it easy to parseJSON using [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Example:

```
 var json = $.parseJSON("[{ name: 'Bill', age: 22, hair: 'Brown' }]");
```

Then can easily get the data like this:

```
 var name = json[0].name; var age = json[0].age; ....
```

Is this something not possible in C#?  I saw how JSON.Net reads JSON and exposes it in C#, and it's quite a task to work with it.

Isn't there a way to easily/quickly get JSON just like you can in jQuery?

(and without having to write static code first JSON to Object Class properties to match the JSON object.)

Comment: @Remus Rusanu How could this be duplicate when I clearly state *(and without having to write static code first JSON to Object Class properties to match the JSON object.)* ???

Comment: Json.NET does not require class definitions to deserialize. You can call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and use dynamic to access the properties. That is exactly what is in some of the answers in the duplicate.

Comment: I should had choose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the properties of your class match the names in the Json string, you can use :

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = 
    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
MyClass obj = (MyClass)serializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
```

Comment: What if there is no class with properties to define it?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904825/c-sharp-deserialize-json-to-anonymous-object