# Add HTML attribute to anonymous type without changing method signature

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, extension-methods, html-helper

I have an HtmlHelper extension method that I am writing for an MVC/Razor website. The method signature is as follows:

```
public static IHtmlString CharacterCountOf<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Func<Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, object, IHtmlString> helperMethod,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        object htmlAttributes){}
```

If you notice I am taking a method signature in as a parameter. These methods are typically going to be other HtmlHelper methods like `TextAreaFor()`. The `object` in the method signature are the html attributes. What I would like to do is take the anonymous type, add my own attribute to the object, and then call the method signature that was passed in as a parameter. Like so:

```
var identifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
// somehow add identifier to htmlAttributes
helperMethod(expression, htmlAttributes)
```

All of the solutions that I have come across either change the htmlAttributes into an `IDictionary` which then won't work for the method signature or require you to know how the anonymous type was structured.

Here are some of the different approaches that I have tried/looked into: [Use a Json object to construct an anonymous type,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904825/c-sharp-deserialize-json-to-anonymous-object?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) [Use an extension method to map a dictionary to an anonymous type](https://jacobcarpenter.wordpress.com/2008/03/13/dictionary-to-anonymous-type/) or [convert the anonymous type to a dictionary, expandoObject, or dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595416/convert-dictionarystring-object-to-anonymous-object?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Since it was suggested here is why I am asking this question:
This method is being used to generate the HTML/JS that counts the number of characters in a textbox/area and displays that count in the bottom right corner. I originally had all of the code in HTML/JS but while I was refactoring the existing text inputs I found that the number of steps needed to implement this functionality were annoying and fiddly. I could use C# to always include the annoying bits that make this work. With the new method refactoring and adding this feature to new text inputs becomes very easy.

Originally I tried firing the JS events on the name attribute which gets generated `$([name='Description']).on('keyup')` which worked great until I ran into a problem when there where more than one element with that attribute and value in the DOM. Therefore I needed a way to add a unique identifier to the HTML element that the JS would use to watch the text input.

Comment: Maybe you also want to explain `X` . (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I will modify my question.