# Deserialize JSON array of mixed content

Tags: c#, json, silverlight

**Apolgies: I forget to mention this is for a Silverlight Solution.**

A JSON string is returned from a service as:

```
{
   "710 HUVAL ST (N), LAFAYETTE LA":{
      "confidence":0.844,
      "fips_county":"22055",
      "country_code":"US",
      "country_code3":"USA",
      "latitude":30.234912,
      "street_address":"710 Huval St",
      "country_name":"United States",
      "longitude":-92.034597,
      "street_number":"710",
      "region":"LA",
      "street_name":"Huval St",
      "locality":"Lafayette"
   },
   "200 ASHLAND PARK, LAFAYETTE LA":{
      "confidence":0.844,
      "fips_county":"22055",
      "country_code":"US",
      "country_code3":"USA",
      "latitude":30.159882,
      "street_address":"200 Ashland Park Dr",
      "country_name":"United States",
      "longitude":-92.035342,
      "street_number":"200",
      "region":"LA",
      "street_name":"Ashland Park Dr",
      "locality":"Lafayette"
   }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it into a .NET class.  However, I'm running into trouble because each object in the array (and it may be very large, I'm just showing two in the example above) looks to be a different object type to the JSON deserializer in .NET.

Using a tool like JSON to C# to generate the classes will create a class for each of the array objects, which is not ideal given that the results vary from response to response.

I cannot for the life of me figure out the appropriate class(es) to generate in .NET in order to be able to deserialize it.  I don't have any control of the JSON service and I am stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671972/deserializing-json-to-anonymous-object-in-c-sharp   The idea isn't to deserialize the data into a concrete class but an anonymous object or similar primitive.

Comment: I apologize.  I completely left out the fact that this is in Silverlight.

Comment: Perhaps this will work for you - http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/how-to-convert-json-to-expandoobject/  Last time I worked with C#, I generally avoided anything that relied on class reflection for JSON (de)serialization as it seemed to flaky.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [JSON.NET package from nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json).  The class `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` will give you an interface similar to `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` that will allow you to parse the JSON without having to deserialize it into a single concrete object.