# How can I deserialize a JSON object that uses unspecified and variable property names

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JSON response (which I have no control over) similar to this:

```
{"response":{
  "a" : "value of a",
  "b" : "value of b",
  "c" : "value of c",
  ...
}}
```

Where:

- "a", "b", "c" are unknown names upfront.
- The number of items can vary.

All I need at the end is an array of strings for all the values. Keeping the names is a bonus (Dictionary?) but I need to browse values by the order in which they appear.

How would you achieve this using JSON.NET?

Comment: Why can't you just use the `JavaScriptSerializer`? No need for third party tools in this case :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `JObject` class from the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace to deserialize the object into a DOM-like structure:

```
public class StackOverflow_10608188
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        string json = @"{""response"":{
          ""a"" : ""value of a"",
          ""b"" : ""value of b"",
          ""c"" : ""value of c""
        }}";
        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
        foreach (JProperty property in jo["response"].Children())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works but not very pretty. I believe you can exchange to json.net with `JavaScriptSerializer`.

```
var json = "{\"response\":{\"a\":\"value of a\",\"b\":\"value of b\",\"c\":\"value of c\"}}";
var x = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var res = x.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>>>(json);

foreach (var key in res.Keys)
{
    foreach (var subkey in res[key].Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(res[key][subkey]);
    }
}
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(res["response"]["a"]);
Console.WriteLine(res["response"]["b"]);
Console.WriteLine(res["response"]["c"]);
```

output:

```
value of a
value of b
value of c
```

Comment: Either don't define the `Blah` class, or use it for the deserialization.

Comment: oops, Blah class is not needed. i'll del it.