# How do I parse this JSON (using JSON.NET)?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have some JSON which is valid but a little quirky looking. Here it is:

```
{
"server":"some server name",
"files":
{
"filename1":{"source":"original","format":"text"},
"filename2":{"source":"original","format":"text"},
"filename3":{"source":"original","format":"text"}
}
}
```

As you can see, the "files" section contains one JSON object per "file" so I can get this as array of JTokens but not sure how to get the values of "filename1", "filename2", etc. out.

I'm using JSON.NET and C# so please don't provide an answer that requires the JavaScriptSerializer from System.Web.Extensions.dll. Either pure JObject/JToken calls or JConvert.DeserializeObject<> would be okay.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you stuck with that format?

Comment: Yes it's a format coming from the server and can't be changed.

Comment: Why don't you combine the attributes to {server:"name",  files :{filename:, "file1",format:" text", source:"original"}}}

Comment: @lafama If I could change the JSON I would but that's not the problem. The problem is given this JSON output how would I get the filename values?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        Files = new Dictionary<string, FileData>();
    }
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, FileData> Files { get; set; } 
}
public class FileData
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
}
```

Then Access it using this

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(JsonValue);
```

Comment: should note that the values the OP wants will be enumerable from `result.Files.Keys`

Answer (score 2):

How about using dynamic deserialization? See [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

```
string json = @"{""server"":""some server name"",""files"":{""filename1"":{""source"":""original"",""format"":""text""},""filename2"":{""source"":""original"",""format"":""text""},""filename3"":{""source"":""original"",""format"":""text""}}}";
dynamic result = JObject.Parse(json);

Console.WriteLine(result.server);
foreach (dynamic file in result.files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
    dynamic value = file.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(value.source);
    Console.WriteLine(value.format);
}
```

Output

```
some server name
filename1
original
text
filename2
original
text
filename3
original
text
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define a class like this:

```
class ClassName
{
    public string server;
    public ClassName2 files;
}
```

and define ClassName2:

```
class ClassName2
{
    ClassName3 filename1;
    ClassName3 filename2;
    ClassName3 filename3;
}
```

and finally ClassName3

```
ClassName3
{
    public string source;
    public string format;
}
```

supporse you have saved your json data in a string variable like 'result'

```
 ClassName fin = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(result);
```

this will give you anything you need.

Comment: This is good and would work however one catch. The filename is different in the dataset. So while this works in the snippet I posted, it doesn't work when there's "filename10" or "filename_123.zip". The names are dynamic and determined at runtime and will be different with each call so need something that can handle that.

Comment: if your filenames are dynamic it is better to define them as array.

Comment: Agreed, just looking how to do that (although I'm working through the answer @lafama proposed below and it looks like it will work)