# Is it possible to generate C# class by deserialization some protocol?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I need to generate or define new class based on deserialization serialized class. So I want to transfer class definition from server to client to have access to it's properties later.

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One portable way to transfer the property definitions and the data itself is to use the JSON serializer.

You can deserialize into a `dynamic` object using JSON.Net

[Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: For WCF this is likely the worst idea -> on the other hand DTO contracts dll is likely the best & schema definitions is somewhere in the middle

Comment: @user1416420: Sure, I would use a contract pre-understood by both parties.  However, my interpretation of the question is how to transport the schema over the wire as well as the data.  JSON does that well.  Of course, a web service can also publish its schema using XML.  Without knowing the requirement behind the request, it's hard to say with certainty what the "proper" way is.

Answer (score 1):

**Proper way** to do it would be to either expose a [schema definition for your service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx#S6) for clients to consume & generate strongly type class definitions from that  or provide a DLL with your DTO contract definitions (class/interface definitions) to the client.

If you chose neither of those approaches (no schema & no dll with interfaces) but still 
want to generate a class definition, you can in an **improper way** generate .cs class definitions, from a sample data of the service (call the services couple of times and intercept the responses or use some [http client](http://web-sniffer.net/)). However this approach does not guarantee that you will get an accurate or/and complete generation. Basically you can go from:

[XML->XSD->C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) cs class file (or even [XML to C# cs file directly](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlDataBinding/Xml-Schema-To-Cs.aspx))or [JSON->C# class file](http://json2csharp.com/)

And deserializing object to dynamic especially when you don't own both the server & client code is pretty much the worst thing you can do. And this way **you didn't transfer you class definition to the client**. Deserializng to dynamic objects is actually no desrialization at all as matter of fact, it gives you a dictionary of strings with syntactical sugar to access them as properties at runtime with not compile time support which can be equal to a disaster. In short don't do it unless you own all the code (not that it's a good idea then either but maybe you could get by somehow)