# How to get some values from a JSON string in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I have a string and I want to get some values from it.

My strings seem like:

string1:

```
"{\r\n   \"id\": \"100000280905615\",
 \r\n \"name\": \"Jerard Jones\",
 \r\n   \"first_name\": \"Jerard\",
 \r\n   \"last_name\": \"Jones\",
 \r\n   \"link\": \"https://www.facebook.com/Jerard.Jones\",
 \r\n   \"username\": \"Jerard.Jones\",
 \r\n   \"gender\": \"female\",
 \r\n   \"locale\": \"en_US\"\r\n}"
```

string2:

```
"{\r\n   \"id\": \"100000390001929\",
  \r\n   \"name\": \"\\u05d1\\u05d2\\u05e8\\u15dc\\u25d9 \\u05d1\\u05e8\\u05d5\\u05e9\",
  \r\n   \"first_name\": \"\\u05d4\\u05d2\\u05e7\\u02dc\\u05d9\",
  \r\n   \"last_name\": \"\\u05d1\\u05e8\\u05d5\\u05e9\",
  \r\n   \"link\": "https://www.facebook.com/people/\\u05d2\\u05d1\\u05e@\\u05dc\\u05d9-\\u05d1\\u05e8\\u05d4\\u05e9/100000390001929\",
  \r\n   \"gender\": \"female\",
  \r\n   \"locale\": \"he_IL\"\r\n}"
```

Unfortunately, there is a situation that a string will be by the same concept, but without some parameters:

string3:

```
"{\r\n   \"id\": \"100000390001929\",
  \r\n   \"last_name\": \"\\u05d1\\u05e8\\u05d5\\u05e9\",
  \r\n   \"gender\": \"female\",
  \r\n   \"locale\": \"he_IL\"\r\n}"
```

How can I get the values of: `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `locale`?

Comment: Looks like you need a [JSON parser](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+parse+json).

Comment: I'd use Regex or JSON libs for that one. Seems like the best bet.

Comment: What about substring.

Comment: looks like JSON http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Comment: See: [Deserializing JSON string into dynamic object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8972079/439427)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Your strings are JSON formatted, so you will need to *parse it* into a object. For that you can use [JSON.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json).

Here is an example on how to parse a JSON string into a dynamic object:

```
string source = "{\r\n   \"id\": \"100000280905615\", \r\n \"name\": \"Jerard Jones\",  \r\n   \"first_name\": \"Jerard\", \r\n   \"last_name\": \"Jones\", \r\n   \"link\": \"https://www.facebook.com/Jerard.Jones\", \r\n   \"username\": \"Jerard.Jones\", \r\n   \"gender\": \"female\", \r\n   \"locale\": \"en_US\"\r\n}";
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(source);
Console.WriteLine(data.id);
Console.WriteLine(data.first_name);
Console.WriteLine(data.last_name);
Console.WriteLine(data.gender);
Console.WriteLine(data.locale);
```

Comment: thank you.. I used:
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(elements[0].Text);

Comment: This is all good but until you have a dynamic string you need to get from the json. eg Users.{ID}.Username

Comment: EDIT: found a way using this method:-
String username = data["Users"]["" + User]["Username"];

Comment: Love the `dynamic` usage here! +1

Comment: If I try to return a property(for example result) from the dynamic objetc, returns null :s

Comment: using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

Comment: Thanks... In my case, it wasn't working, returning NULL, so I continued with:
```
var parsedData = JObject.Parse(payload);
var elementId = parsedData["entity"]["element"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 29):

Following code is working for me.

Usings:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Code:

```
 using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            string json = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                            string data = JObject.Parse(json)["id"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }

//json = {"kind": "ALL", "id": "1221455", "longUrl": "NewURL"}
```

Answer (score 25):

A .NET 6 version using `System.Text.Json`

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = @"{ ""id"" : 123 }";
        
        //parse it
        var yourObject = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
        //retrieve the value
        var id= yourObject.RootElement
                          .GetProperty("id");
        
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
```

To retrieve nested properties, you can chain the `GetProperty` calls. As a more advanced example:

```
//access first element of array "persons" get nested property "age" 
var age = yourObject.rootElement.GetProperty("persons")[0]
                                .GetProperty("age");
```

Answer (score 23):

my string

```
var obj = {"Status":0,"Data":{"guid":"","invitationGuid":"","entityGuid":"387E22AD69-4910-430C-AC16-8044EE4A6B24443545DD"},"Extension":null}
```

Following code to get guid:

```
var userObj = JObject.Parse(obj);
var userGuid = Convert.ToString(userObj["Data"]["guid"]);
```

Comment: I think your string is not a string ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Create a class like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string First_Name {get; set;}
    public string Last_Name {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Gender {get; set;}
    public string Locale {get; set;}
}
```

(I'm not 100% sure, but if that doesn't work you'll need use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` for `DataContractJsonSerializer`.)

Then create `JSonSerializer`:

```
private static readonly XmlObjectSerializer Serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Data));
```

and deserialize object:

```
// convert string to stream
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents);
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    (Data)Serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}
```

Comment: Json.NET is far better than DataContractJsonSerializer. See the feature comparison table: http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: And ServiceStack.Text is far better than JSON.Net.

Comment: I like Json.NET but this is a good answer that doesn't introduce a lot of external code and it easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this alternative specifying the expected type:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

string jsonString = "{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\": 30}";

Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(jsonString);
```