# windows phone 8 data binding to an array

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, datacontext

I'm a windows phone 8 novice, struggling at the moment with xaml data-binding with arrays.

**XAML:**

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LocationsData" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding vicinity}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,-6,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

**.CS**

```
LocationsData.DataContext = _array_of_locations;
```

The `_array_of_locations` has 4 items,

[image]

each of them is a valid JSON,

```
{
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.923101,
            "lng": 77.586057
        }
    },
    "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    "id": "9a769bc2faaa79fe0ffbd85c2c28446940153331",
    "name": "Domino's Pizza",
    "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": false
    },
    "price_level": 1,
    "rating": 2.9,
    "reference": "CnRsAAAAsI0LvfwZ_RC8PEDsJS3TfKkRkTn7d_2_-vw8tu_SYBYCJk2CmKt6RyRJtO5mG0Weq-R0jSsmyQOWHjU45itlrH1cN89EqgIA9Vtmvcih1xi6ZwpNewqZ8mNCQWWLDJvcT3AQLHGnFcn4E9a30Gvs9xIQeKGVsrSOKLDx4vYCjixIKhoUOGeosCJIVFDmE3-3qIPcIM7PSCs",
    "types": [
        "restaurant",
        "food",
        "establishment"
    ],
    "vicinity": "11th Main Road, Jayanagar, Bangalore"
}
```

It's not working, I'm getting lost with all the documentation as I don't come from a c# background. So how do I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the arrays here, it's the fact that the source of a data binding (i.e. the `name` and `vicinity` in `{Binding name}` and `{Binding vicinity}`) must be a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).  The objects in your array don't have properties with names `name` and `vicinity`, so nothing gets shown.  In fact, you might even see binding errors in the Output window in Visual Studio, mentioning that it couldn't find `name` and `vicinity` properties.

I suspect you have got four items in your `LongListSelector`, but because none of them have any text in them, they have zero size and you don't see them.  Try adding  a `TextBlock` with some static text (e.g. `<TextBlock Text="X"/>`) to your `StackPanel` to see if four `X`s appear.

If you just need to show the JSON read-only, then it should be possible to deserialize the JSON to [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).  An anonymous type will then be created for each JSON object, with one (.NET) property for each property in the JSON object.  See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net).  With any luck that should work, however, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Cool, will give this and try and keep you posted. Thanks for your time on this, much appreciated :)