# Deserialize Json List to C# List objects

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I have class which return json string but I want to deserilize it into C# List Objects. My current code look like this

```
public class JsonBuilder
    {
        public static string BuildJson(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
        {
            var list = new List<dynamic>();

           // create list with json object from service

            var jsonObjList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
            var des = (List<JsonObject>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonObjList, typeof(List<JsonObject>));

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
        }
```

Exception thrown when it tries to deserialize the "serialized" json  string

```
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error converting value 


InnerException:

{"Could not cast or convert from System.String to MvcWebApp.Models.JsonObject."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
var des = (List<DeserializeObjects>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonObjList, jsonObjList.GetType()));
```

or this:

```
var des = (List<DeserializeObjects>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonObjList, typeof(List<dynamic>));
```

else this post could also help you to achieve your goal:

[Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the trick work for me. Any suggestion?

Comment: I found a solution from the link you have given. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var jsonObjList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
 dynamic resultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonObjList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with this `class`

```
public class Author
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string nickname { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class CustomFields
{
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string title_plain { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string excerpt { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string modified { get; set; }
    public List<object> categories { get; set; }
    public List<object> tags { get; set; }
    public Author author { get; set; }
    public List<object> comments { get; set; }
    public List<object> attachments { get; set; }
    public int comment_count { get; set; }
    public string comment_status { get; set; }
    public CustomFields custom_fields { get; set; }
}

public class YourObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int count_total { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
    public List<Post> posts { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you deserialize with this :

```
var yourObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(json);
```