# Json.NET - deserialize directly from a stream to a dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, json, stream, json.net

With a little help from the [performance tips](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Performance.htm) in the Json.NET docs, I put together a method for downloading/deserializing JSON from a remote resource:

```
public async Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(string url) 
{
  using (var stream = await new HttpClient().GetStreamAsync(url))
  {
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
      using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
      {
        return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<T>(jr);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to have a non-generic version that returns a `dynamic`. Calling the above method with `GetJsonAsync<dynamic>(url)` works, until you try to access a dynamic property on the result, at which point I get:

```
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for '[MyProperty]'
```

I have seen [how to deserialize to a dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net) from a string, but have not seen a working example of doing it directly from a stream, which would be preferable as it is more memory efficient. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure you have a stream with json in it, and json with a MyProperty at whatever location you're accessing it from?  Can you produce this with a `MemoryStream`?

Comment: Absolutely certain. I created a class with MyProperty and tested the same endpoint using that (`GetJsonAsync<MyClass>`) and it returned exactly what I expected. No go with the dynamic version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out this had little to do with Json.NET and more to do with my understanding of dynamics (which I rarely use). Thanks to @Peter Richie, I found that `GetJsonAsync<dynamic>` does work if I explicitly cast MyProperty to a string. But I'd rather not have to do that. Using my original method and a [real working endpoint](http://echo.jsontest.com/MyProperty/MyValue), here are 3 scenarios; only the last one works:

```
var url = "http://echo.jsontest.com/MyProperty/MyValue"; // great testing site!

var x1 = await GetJsonAsync<dynamic>(url);
Assert.AreEqual("MyValue", x1.MyProperty); // fail!

dynamic x2 = await GetJsonAsync<dynamic>(url);
Assert.AreEqual("MyValue", x2.MyProperty); // fail!

dynamic x3 = await GetJsonAsync<ExpandoObject>(url);
Assert.AreEqual("MyValue", x3.MyProperty); // pass!
```

Armed with that knowledge, the non-generic overload of my original method looks like this:

```
public async Task<dynamic> GetJsonAsync(string url) {
    dynamic d = await GetJsonAsync<ExpandoObject>(url);
    return d;
}
```

And users can do this:

```
var x = await GetJsonAsync(url);
Assert.AreEqual("MyValue", x.MyProperty); // pass!
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there's some information you haven't provided.  The following works fine for me:

```
    private T ReadJson<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            {
                dynamic d = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize(jr);
                return d;
            }
        }
    }
//...

var d = ReadJson<dynamic>(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{'MyProperty' : 'MyValue'}")));
Debug.WriteLine((String)d.MyProperty);
```

Comment: Thanks, your explicit cast MyProperty to a string is what pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, technically the `MyProperty` property is a type of `JValue`--which doesn't have an implicit conversion to `string`.