# Error converting value "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[]" to type 'WebApiTestDefinition.obJson'. Path '', line 1, position 63

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I tried to deserialize the json data but it was showing error like this.

```
public ActionResult Test(Login Log)      
{          
        string sStudName = "ram";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(StudentAPI);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); // this depends on whether you want to get back json or XML            
        var loginResp = client.PostAsJsonAsync(StudentAPI, Log).Result;
        if (loginResp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //if (loginResp == null)
            //{
                var msg = loginResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
                obJson res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<obJson>(loginResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                return Json(Log, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //}
            //return Redirect("/Admission/Registration");
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return View();
}
```

Comment: possibly you need `msg.Result` instead `loginResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`, because otherwise you try read twice

Comment: what is `obJson` class? can you provide it declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net) (it refers to JSON.net)

So in your case you should try (if using JSON.net is possible)

```
var msg = ""; // Get json message as string                    
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(msg); 
// Do something with this JSON
```