# Deserialize stringified JSON object

Tags: c#, .net, json

I've read a few posts on how to do this, but everything that i've seen the JSON object has specific property names to query, where i do not.

Here is my JSON string:

```
{
  "424406": true,
  "425171": true,
  "411961": true
}
```

I want to loop through the array and read the string and bool field in separately (the JSON string is stored in a hidden variable, then accessed in my asp.net code behind):

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(partDetailsSelectedItems.Value);

foreach (dynamic x in dynObj)
{
   string Id = ????
   bool boolValue = ???
}
```

how do i get each of the 2 objects in "x" without specifying the name?

Ideally, i'd like to convert this stringified JSON into a generic list

```
List<string,bool>
```

but i need to understand how to handle my above scenario.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8972079/1017882 < try that

Comment: He's specifying the property names in his loop, i have no property names...

Comment: If you don't want to explicitly reference them then try serializing it to a dictionary? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1212115/1017882 That way you don't have to have any knowledge of the keys or values being fed in, and can still iterate over it.

Comment: Deserialize to `Dictionary<string,bool>`

Comment: @DeeMac, nailed it. Thank you

Comment: @L.B: Nice - added that to my answer. Hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use LINQ to JSON it's simple, because `JObject` allows you to iterate over all the key/value pairs - it implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var json = JObject.Parse(text);

        foreach (var pair in json)
        {
            string id = pair.Key;
            bool value = (bool) pair.Value;
            Console.WriteLine("id: {0}; value: {1}", id, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The cast for the value is calling the [explicit conversion](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit.htm) from `JToken` to `bool`. No need for `dynamic` here at all.

Alternatively, as noted in comments, you can just deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, bool>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, bool>>(text);

        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
        {
            string id = pair.Key;
            bool value = pair.Value;
            Console.WriteLine("id: {0}; value: {1}", id, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I usually end up using LINQ to JSON myself, but either approach works and which is better depends on your context.

Comment: @John Skeet, thank you. I did not know i could easily deserialize to a dictionary

Comment: The second part to this answer was really what my original answer was (poorly) trying to get at....deserialize as a  dictionary rather than `dynamic`. There was no point in re-editing it to repeat the same code.

Comment: @James your code will get an *InvalidCastException*

Comment: @L.B not if it was an `ExpandoObject`, that was the issue with my answer to begin with, I was just assuming it was.