# Deserialise JSON with Json.Net and test content of array

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm deserialising JSON using JSON.Net along the same lines as the accepted solution to this question: [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net).  Essentially:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");

Console.WriteLine(d.number);
Console.WriteLine(d.str);
Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);
```

Difference being my array has strings rather than numbers. The above methods work fine.  However, what I want to do is test if the array contains a particular value.  If it was a typed array of strings I could use myArray.IndexOf("ValueToFind") and if it returns a value > -1 then it's in there.  However, this isn't working and I think it's because it's actually an array of JValues rather than strings.

I can iterate through the array, cast each one to a string and then test (i.e. a foreach loop with an if statement inside) but I was hoping for a more succinct single line test.  Can anyone advise if there is a simpler way to do the test?

Thanks

Comment: I'm too lazy to try this but could you not use the extension method Any() such as if ( d.Any(p => p.ToString() == "Whatever") ) { //etc.. }

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I get the message: "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.NET can seamlessly convert `JArray` to `List<string>`, so you can use

```
Console.WriteLine(d.array.ToObject<List<string>>().IndexOf("1"));
```

This works even with JSON integer array.

Answer (score 1):

I got a slightly messier answer by first converting your dynamic array to a known type:

```
IEnumerable<JToken> d2 = d.array;
```

Then you can use Any as an extension method.

```
if (d2.Any(p => p.ToString() == "1")) //etc.
```