# Deserialize JSON in C# without creating a class

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm looking for a way to deserialize a string coming from an API. The Json string is just : {"key" : "lolo"}.

I dont want to create a class for this.
I have found this but it's kind of old so I don't know if there is something better today: [Json deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

In the future I will use more Json deserialization so I would like to use JSON.NET.
Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net

or

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json.

Used in almost every .net appilication these days.

Comment: Thanks, but in the top right corner, the examples. He create a Movie class. And I don't want to create a class for one value.

Comment: You can also deserialize to dictionaries:
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>("{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }")`

Comment: @null This should be a part of the answer as it is the main argument why using netwonsofts library would work.

Comment: Use **dynamic** datatype. like -

`dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result.ToString());`