# c# take certain words from String

Tags: c#, extract

When I get http response it looks like this:

```
{
"course_editions": {
"2014/SL": [
  {
    "course_id": "06-DEGZLI0",
    "term_id": "2014/SL",
    "course_name": {
      "en": "Preparation for bachelor exam",
    }
  },
  {
    "course_id": "06-DPRALW0",
    "term_id": "2014/SL",
    "course_name": {
      "en": "Work experience",
    }
  },
  {
```

I would like to be able to extract course title only, f.e.:

```
Work experience
Preparation for bachelor exam
```

I've tried this:

```
string probably_json = GetResponse(url_courses);
object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(probably_json);
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(obj.ToString().Replace("\\t", "    ").Replace("\\n", "\n")))
            {
                string line;
                int lineNo = 0;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("en"))
                    {
                        string output = line.Substring(0, line.Length-1);
                        Console.WriteLine(output);
                    }
                    ++lineNo;
                }
            } // End Using StreamReader
```

But that's all I've got:

```
"en": "Preparation for bachelor exam"          "en": "Work experience"
```

what am I supposed to do, to get course title only ?

Comment: Why can't you go through properties returned by DeserializeObject?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net , it explains how to use JsonConvert with a dynamic object. You don't need to use StringReader, just call obj.course_name.en

Answer (score 2):

If you are using json.net anyways, make it do some work, don't parse yourself:

```
var result = JObject
    .Parse(probably_json)
    .SelectTokens("['course_editions'].['2014/SL'].[*].['course_name'].['en']");
```