# JSON.NET to deserialize dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, azure-api-apps

I have JSON data:

```
var decodedJson =
"{{
  "user": {
    "userId": "sid:C4F4E93856104F078A11FE95892F0158"
  },
  "authenticationToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmdWxscm93IjoiYWxsIiwiRGJnMiI6ImxvZ2luIiwidmVyIjoiMyIsInVpZCI6InNpZDpDNEY0RTkzODU2MTA0RjA3OEExMUZFOTU4OTJGMDE1OCIsImlzcyI6InVybjptaWNyb3NvZnQ6d2luZG93cy1henVyZTp6dW1vIiwiYXVkIjoidXJuOm1pY3Jvc29mdDp3aW5kb3dzLWF6dXJlOnp1bW8iLCJleHAiOjE0NDk3NTYzNzIsIm5iZiI6MTQ0NzE2NDM3Mn0.kc-0O_aorfTw9l9U6yY6wyVtQnckqNBJikBzxAcJZ_U"
}}";
```

Then I want to deserialize it dynamically  using JSON.NET:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(decodedJson);
```

Then I expect to extract the UserId and Token like this:

```
string userId = result.user.userId;
string userToken = result.authenticationToken;
```

But it is saying

> "Unknown member user/ authenticationToken"

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATED:**

I have copied wrong json data, it actually should be like this:

```
{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"sid:C4F4E93856104F078A11FE95892F0158\"},\"authenticationToken\":\"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmdWxscm93IjoiYWxsIiwiRGJnMiI6ImxvZ2luIiwidmVyIjoiMyIsInVpZCI6InNpZDpDNEY0RTkzODU2MTA0RjA3OEExMUZFOTU4OTJGMDE1OCIsImlzcyI6InVybjptaWNyb3NvZnQ6d2luZG93cy1henVyZTp6dW1vIiwiYXVkIjoidXJuOm1pY3Jvc29mdDp3aW5kb3dzLWF6dXJlOnp1bW8iLCJleHAiOjE0NDk3NjE1NDEsIm5iZiI6MTQ0NzE2OTU0MX0.oVH8R2134UQQDpXfzPv2mmrj7M05w2mzWtbp70i7GEU\"}
```

Comment: Since you know the JSON structure, can't your serialize to a standard type?

Comment: @ArghyaC: The jSon data may change in the future. Anyway I have followed this code sample from Microsoft Azure API https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-consume/

Comment: Have you tried removing the opening `{` and closing `}`, you have 2 on start and on end and that's illegal in JSON. You can also try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8972079/2096538

Comment: Sorry I have copied wrong json data, just updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the long run you would be better to copy the structure in the C# exactly. If your model changes for json then you will have to change your `dynamic` code anyway and the bugs are easier to creep in.

The following classes can be used to parse your json after removing the extra `{}`at the start and end of the response.

```
public class User
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public User user { get; set; }
    public string authenticationToken { get; set; }
}
```

You can utilise the following site to quickly map JSON to CSharp

http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Thanks. I know it but I just follow the instruction from Microsoft example page and want to know what wrong with it: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-consume/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extra set of curly braces "{}" around the entire object in the JSON string. Have you tried removing those to see if it works?

I pasted your JSON string in a few web-based [JSON formatters](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) and they all threw errors until I removed the outermost curly braces.

Comment: To the OP - if you receive double braces, you can remove them using : `jsonString = jsonString.Substring(1, jsonString.Length - 2);`

Comment: In some cases valid json when parsed with JSON.Net, the extra curly brackets are added for some reason?? That's what I am stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

One way, is to use [`Linq-to-JSON`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) of `Json.NET` like this

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\user.json");
var jObjet = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

string userId = (string)jObjet["user"]["userId"];
string userToken = (string)jObjet["authenticationToken"];
```

If your object structure changes in future, you can pass the new `string` tag names as parameter to your method.

**Note**
Your `JSON` structure is not correct, you have an extra set of braces `{}` around the object.