# Parse Dynamic JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I am getting a JSON response from a server but the JSON is not in a one format. So obviously there is no point of creating classes to deserialize it. So, I tried to use `dynamic` but I am unable to read the response.

The sample JSON String is

```
" {"hm_xytrict":"HM Tricky District - oop","hmSD":"HM Pool District"}"
```

Note that "hm_xytrict" and "hmSD" will be different every time

I am using

```
dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
```

For this specific case I can use `jsonResponse.hm_xytrict` and `jsonResponse.hmSD` but since they are also dynamic so how can I read `jsonResponse` for all cases.

Thank you,
Hamza

Comment: Use JObject instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can use a different part of the JSON.NET api to parse and extract data from your object:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (JProperty element in jObj.Children())
{
    string propName = element.Name;
    var propVal = (string)element.Value;
}
```

Comment: Don't even need to read the individual elements, you can deserialize to dynamic from JSON.net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net

Answer (score 0):

Even more interesting, you can directly parse a JSON string to a dynamic object

```
string responseString = @"{""hm_xytrict"":""HM Tricky District - oop"",""hmSD"":""HM Pool District""}";

dynamic jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(responseString);
foreach (var item in jsonResponse)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Which in your example will output

```
hm_xytrict
HM Tricky District - oop
hmSD 
HM Pool District
```