# Dynamic with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize some Json into a Dynamic using Json.NET.  Following the examples given at [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net). I've got most of the way there, however I'm having difficulty with one part of the Json where it includes [] around the contents.  I've placed the returned Json at the top of the top below.

```
//{ "coord":{ "lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],
//  "base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":283.582,"pressure":1024.62,"humidity":91,"temp_min":283.582,"temp_max":283.582,
//  "sea_level":1034.82,"grnd_level":1024.62},"wind":{"speed":6.61,"deg":222},"clouds":{"all":92},"dt":1449047315,
//"sys":{"message":0.0052,"country":"GB","sunrise":1449042313,"sunset":1449071662},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}

var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0";

// Synchronous Consumption
var syncClient = new WebClient();
var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

dynamic d = JObject.Parse(content);

//Can now do d.weather

dynamic d2 = d.weather;
//var weatherMain = d.weather.main; // this doesn't work :( -- I think because because the sub-json has more [] around it

dynamic d3 = d.coord;
var lon = d3.lon; //this works

var pink = 2;
```

I would like to retrieve the value of d.weather.main, but I think the [] brackets are preventing it.  I've tried replacing them, but it seems to break the dynamic structure if I do this.

Comment: These "`[]` around contents" is an array notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide the index of the `weather` instance you want to get since your `weather` property in your JSON is an array (indicated by the `[]` surrounding it):

```
d.weather[0].main;
```