# Is it possible to use Json.Net to deserialise a BSON file to a dynamic object?

Tags: json.net, bson

I have a BSON file, is there any way I can tell Json.Net to deserialise that to a dynamic object like in [this example for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just deserialize as type `dynamic` (or [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) or [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) following the instructions in [Deserialize from BSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeFromBson.htm):

```
        dynamic result;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        using (var reader = new BsonReader(stream))
        {
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
            result = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader); // Or ExpandoObject or JToken
        }
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LkZ8BA).

To stream directly from a file, use a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
        string path = "bsonData.bson";  // Or whatever
        dynamic result;

        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path)) 
        using (var reader = new BsonReader(stream))
        {
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
            result = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader); // Or ExpandoObject or JToken
        }
```