# Parse JSON elegantly

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api controller in .NET Core 2.1, which receives

```
JToken jsonBody
```

The json has the following structure

```
{
  "id": "xxx",
  "payload": {
    "TelephoneNumber": "1111",
    "Name": "Hans"
  }
}
```

and more fields, but it's irrelevant.
I  want to retrieve the Number and Name elegantly. Currently, I do the following, which I'm sure could be done in a nicer way:

```
var payload = JObject.Parse(jsonBody.SelectToken("Payload").ToString());
            telephoneNumber = new TelephoneNumber(payload.SelectToken("TelephoneNumber").ToString());
```

I've tried just doing

```
jsonBody.SelectToken("Payload.TelephoneNumber")
```

but that doesn't work. I think that it's because somehow the jsonBody, that the controller receives, has only parsed the top nodes as json, hence it could be that it regards the value of

```
jsonBody.SelectToken("Payload")
```

as a string.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: I suspect SelectToken returns a JObject already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a specific field from a JSON string without deserializing in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291102/getting-a-specific-field-from-a-json-string-without-deserializing-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You need to do `jsonBody.SelectToken("payload.TelephoneNumber")` not `jsonBody.SelectToken("Payload.TelephoneNumber")` because JSONPath is **case sensitive**.  Otherwise, `SelectToken()` works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/TgLsDj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [official documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) - you can do something like this:

```
var phone = jsonBody["payload"]["TelephoneNumber"].ToString();
var name = jsonBody["payload"]["Name"].ToString();
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/ELJC12630)

Comment: This doesn't work. If I do var test = jsonBody["Payload"]["TelephoneNumber"], then I get the following error "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue."

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. See the live demo I've linked to in my answer. I get correct results.

Answer (score 1):

This is at least a little bit more elegant:

```
var jsonBody = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'id': 'xxx',
  'payload': {
    'TelephoneNumber': '1111',
    'Name': 'Hans'
  }
}");

var phone = jsonBody["payload"]["TelephoneNumber"].Value<string>();
var name = jsonBody["payload"]["Name"].Value<string>();
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If I do var test = jsonBody["Payload"]["TelephoneNumber"], then I get the following error "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue."

Comment: Did you try with lowercase "payload"? The JSON is case sensitive.

Comment: Also make sure that "jsonBody" actually is a JObject or a JToken (and not a "JValue", as it sounds like it is from your error message).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deserialize your full json, you can create a class with the properties you need

```
public class Payload
{
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then use JsonTextReader to deserialize the string:

```
private static Payload DeserializePayload(JToken token)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(token.ToString())))
    {
        reader.CloseInput = true;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject && reader.Path.Equals("payload"))
            {
                var payload = serializer.Deserialize<Payload>(reader);
                return payload;
            }
        }
    }

    // not found - return null? throw exception?
    return null;
}
```

Testing the code:

```
var token = JToken.Parse(@"{
  ""id"": ""xxx"",
  ""payload"": {
    ""TelephoneNumber"": ""1111"",
    ""Name"": ""Hans""
  }
}");

Payload payload = DeserializePayload(token);

Console.WriteLine($"Name: {payload.Name}, Phone number: {payload.TelephoneNumber}");
```