# Not able to parse JSON data properly

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON as below

```
var source = "{'Departments': {'Department': [{'DeptName': 'HR','Deptid': '9228590'},{'DeptName': 'Finance','Deptid': '9295426' }]}}";
```

I need to get all the `Deptid` and `DeptName`

I am using **Newtonsoft.Json** and tried as under

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetInformation();
        }

        private static void GetInformation()
        {
            try
            {
                var source = "{'Departments': {'Department': [{'DeptName': 'HR','Deptid': '9228590'},{'DeptName': 'Finance','Deptid': '9295426' }]}}";
                dynamic stuff =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(source);

                string DeptId = stuff.Deparments.Department[0].Deptid;
                string DeptName = stuff.Deparments.Department[0].DeptName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting Null Reference exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net

Comment: The values are inside of an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object does not have property `DeptId`, only `Depid`. Also, these properties are nested so I guess you need to use something like this:

```
string DeptId = stuff.Departments.Department[0].Depid;
string DeptName = stuff.Departments.Department[0].DeptName;
```

Comment: hi, i have modified that..it was a typo

Comment: stuff.Deparments is coming as null, so it is coming as null reference exception...i have edited my question

Answer (score 2):

You are using **Depid** instead of **Deptid**

It should be:
   string DeptId = stuff.Departments.Department[0].Deptid;

Comment: Apologies, I thought Rafal's answer had already stated that but it looks like he is only talking about the raw JSON.

Comment: Having said that, it looks like he has a typo with stuff.Deparments, where it looks like it should be stuff.Departments ('t' missing).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
stuff.Departments.Department[0].DeptName
stuff.Departments.Department[0].Depid
```

This is just an example to get the first element from the Array. You need to iterate over array to get the name and id for all the objects in the Array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using wrong names for `Objects` like `Departments, Depid`. IF you correct this `objects` name it will work.

```
 string DeptId = stuff.Departments.Department[0].Deptid;
 string DeptName = stuff.Departments.Department[0].DeptName;
```