# How to create column and row wise json structure?

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq

I am trying to create json structure like below:

```
{
  "cols": [
    {
      label: "Types",
      type: "string"
    },
    {
      label: "values",
      type: "number"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      c: [
        {
          v: "Mushrooms"
        },
        {
          v: 3
        },
        
      ]
    },
    {
      c: [
        {
          v: "Olives"
        },
        {
          v: 31
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      c: [
        {
          v: "Zucchini"
        },
        {
          v: 1
        },
        
      ]
    },
    {
      c: [
        {
          v: "Pepperoni"
        },
        {
          v: 2
        },
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This  above values I am getting from here:

```
public class Type
{
    public int Mushrooms { get; set; }
    public int Olives { get; set; }
    public int Zucchini { get; set; }
    public int Pepperoni { get; set; }
  public int Statistics { get; set; } //Ignore properties in final output
    public int Count { get; set; } //Ignore properties in final output
    public int Average { get; set; } //Ignore properties in final output
}

var types = MyRepository<Type>.FirstorDefault();
```

The above query outputs:

> Mushrooms:3
>
> Olives:31 etc..

This is how I have designed a class:

```
public class Cols
{
    public List<Names> Names { get; set; }

}

public class Names
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

But I am getting an output like this:

```
"data": [
    {
      "Names": [
        {
          "label": "Types",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "label": "values",
          "type": "number"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**Update:** Class design

```
 public class Rootobject
    {
        public List<Names> cols { get; set; }
        public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class Names
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public List<C> c { get; set; }
    }

    public class C
    {
        public object v { get; set; } 
    }
```

Still above class design gives me below json structure:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "cols": [
      {
        "label": "Types",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "label": "values",
        "type": "number"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Mushrooms"
          },
          {
            "v": "3"
          },
          {
            "v": "Olives"
          },
          {
            "v": "31"
          },
          {
            "v": "Zucchini"
          },
          {
            "v": "1"
          },
          {
            "v": "Pepperoni"
          },
          {
            "v": "2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For Returning json data I am using this [json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx) class of asp.net mvc.

```
return Json(new {Data = rootObject }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated class design can represent the JSON you need.  The question is, how to allocate and initialize the contents of your `Rootobject`?  You can do so using [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx), specifically by looping through all the public properties of your `Rootobject` with [`Type.GetProperties()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) then querying the value with [`PropertyInfo.GetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
var query = types.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && p.GetGetMethod() != null && p.CanRead)
    .Select(p => new Row { c = new List<C> { new C { v = p.Name }, new C { v = p.GetValue(types, new object[0]) } } });

var root = new Rootobject
{
    cols = new List<Names> { new Names { label = "Types", type = "string" }, new Names { label = "values", type = "number" } },
    rows = query.ToList(),
};

return Json(root, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HioF1e).

If you have a specific list of property names to ignore, you can add those names to a hash set and filter them out:

```
var ignoredPropertyNames = new HashSet<string> { "Statistics", "Average", "Count" };

var query = types.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && p.GetGetMethod() != null && p.CanRead)
    .Where(p => !ignoredPropertyNames.Contains(p.Name))
    .Select(p => new Row { c = new List<C> { new C { v = p.Name }, new C { v = p.GetValue(types, new object[0]) } } });
```

Alternatively, if you have a specific list of property names to include, you can use [`Type.GetProperty(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) to get the corresponding property and proceed as before:

```
var propertyNames = new[] { "Mushrooms", "Olives", "Zucchini", "Pepperoni" };

var query = propertyNames
    .Select(n => types.GetType().GetProperty(n))
    .Where(p => p != null)
    .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && p.GetGetMethod() != null && p.CanRead)
    .Select(p => new Row { c = new List<C> { new C { v = p.Name }, new C { v = p.GetValue(types, new object[0]) } } });
```

Comment: In this type class i have 3 extra properties coming in output.Is it possible to avoid those properties.Like for eg:Those properties are Statistics,Count,Average.I want to avoid this 3 properties in my output.Is this possible??

Comment: @Learning - yes, that could be done.  But first please try to provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem.  Do you know in advance a hardcoded set of properties to serialize, or do you want to mark your class with [attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653979.aspx) indicating which property to serialize or ignore?

Comment: Yes i know in advance that for creating this json structure i want to ignore Statistics,Count and average but i am using this 3 properties elsewhere.So i just want to ignore this 3 properties for this json structure only.See my updated question which now include complete Type class

Answer (score 1):

According to your first json, you classes structure should be like this if you want to serialize it that way:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public List<Names> cols { get; set; }
    public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
}

public class Names
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public List<C> c { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string v { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But here when generating rows array how i will add mushroom,Olives etc as because you have declared v as int

Comment: @Learning sorry fixed

Comment: Sorry but with your class design i am not getting expected json architecture

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net) you can deserialize against a dynamic object and use that object, this will save you of writing suplimentary code where it is not needed:

```
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(yourComplexJson);
```