# Deserialize an Anonymous Type From a Collection

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have my serialized JSON in this format:

```
string json = @"[{"Name": "std_id","Value": "111"}, {"Name": "cust_id","Value": "444"}]"
```

How do I deserialize it to a single anonymous object like this:

```
var paramObj = new {"std_id" = 111, "cust_id" = 444}
```

Comment: [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net).

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: Is the JSON fixed or dynamic?  In other words, can the values of the names change or are they always `std_id` and `cust_id`?  If they can change, then deserializing to an anonymous object isn't going to work because anonymous types are defined at compile time by definition.

Comment: @BrianRogers Yes It is definitely dynamic. both 'Name' and 'Value' will vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said the values of the `Name` and `Value` properties in your JSON objects can vary, you will not be able to deserialize to an anonymous object.  Anonymous types are defined at compile-time, which means you need to know the property names ahead of time to be able to define them.  The only way to get around that is code generation, which I think is going to be overkill for this situation.   Instead, I would suggest you deserialize into a `JObject` with a dynamic variable.   This will get you pretty close to what you want.  Here's how:

```
string json = @"[
  { ""Name"": ""std_id"", ""Value"": ""111"" },
  { ""Name"": ""cust_id"", ""Value"": ""444"" }
]";

dynamic obj = new JObject(JArray.Parse(json)
                  .Select(t => new JProperty((string)t["Name"], t["Value"])));
```

From there, you can access the properties like you would for an anonymous type (assuming you know what they are):

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.std_id);
Console.WriteLine(obj.cust_id);
```

If you don't know what the properties are, you can enumerate them like a dictionary:

```
foreach (var prop in obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MRY2ny

Comment: Fantastic !! Can't get better.. Thanks so much for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Why anonymous object? you should deserialize to a type like below

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then what you actually have is `IEnumerable<RootObjct>`. You can use use Linq and select `First()` from it like

```
RootObject = RootObjects.FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could deserialize it into a dynamic. Like this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserializedResult = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
```

Reference:

- [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var definition = new { Name = "" };
string json1 = @"{'Name':'James'}";
var customer1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json1, definition);
Console.WriteLine(customer1.Name);
string json2 = @"{'Name':'Mike'}";
var customer2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json2, definition);
Console.WriteLine(customer2.Name);
```

source http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm

Answer (score 0):

I know that this solution isn't perfect, but it works for the example provided by you and returns result that looks like `paramObj` in your example.

The idea is to create a custom Json converter.

First, let's create a DTO class to present a name-value item of incomming JSON.

```
public class NameValueJsonItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Converter implementation:

```
public class DynamicJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {        
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);

        if (token == null || token.Type != JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return null;
        }

        List<NameValueJsonItem> parsedJson = token.ToObject<List<NameValueJsonItem>>();

        ExpandoObject result = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (NameValueJsonItem item in parsedJson)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name))
            {
                (result as IDictionary<string, object>)[item.Name] = item.Value;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Sure, you can make it more safe by adding some exceptions handling etc inside the method if you want.

You can use this converter like that:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json, new DynamicJsonConverter());
```

Hope it will help.