# Deserialize dynamic structure with Newtonsoft Json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm getting some problems trying to deserialize a "dynamic" JSON structure in my application.

I'm receiving a json object which have a field, `packages`, that can be valorized as an array of strings or as an array of "objects". So, in some situation I have something like this:

```
"packages" : [ "Test", "Var" ]
```

and somethimes I have:

```
"packages" : [ {
    "id" : "9",
    "name" : "Test"
},
{
    "id" : "19",
    "name" : "Opt"
}]
```

In my domain class I tried to define the packages field this way:

```
public List<object> packages { get; set; }
```

But this seems to work only when I'm deserializing array of strings. When I'm getting objects, instead, the `packages` field in my class is valorized as `null`.

How can I solve this issue? **Can I avoid deserialization just for the `packages` fileld and get the value as a simple string?**

**NOTE**: I also tried to define the field like this:

```
public String packages { get; set; }
```

but I'm getting an exception...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: @Sidewinder94 I don't want a dynamic object as a result. I need to handle just a specific field

Comment: My bad, I seem to have misunderstood the question, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved implementing a custom `JsonConverter`:

```
public class PackagesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        List<string> res = new List<string>();

        var jsonArray = JArray.Load(reader);
        foreach (var i in jsonArray)
        {
            if (i.Count() > 1)
            {
                var name = i["name"];
                res.Add(name.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                res.Add(i.ToString());

            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And applying it to my field:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PackagesConverter))]
public List<String> packages { get; set; }
```

This is working fine...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JToken` to replace `object`

```
public class [YourClassName]
{
    public List<JToken> packages { get; set; }
}
```

then you can `yourObject.packages.First().ToString()`

Comment: this is an interesting suggestion. I'll take a try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to deserialize 2 different input types into 1, which is not something C# likes. The return type of the `Json Parser` must be well defined, meaning it's not possible to have a `List` that sometimes has a `String`, and sometimes some `Object`.

I think the correct way to handle this is to firstly find out what your input looks like, by for instance using some `Regex` expression. After you find out what the input looks like, use the `Json` parser to parse the input to an object that fits your input.

For a list of strings use:

```
class ParsedStrings {
    public List<String> Packages { get; set; }
}
```

For a list of objects use:

```
   class ParsedObjects {
        public List<IdName> Names { get; set; }

        public class IdName {
             public string Id { get; set; }
             public string Name { get; set; }
        }
   }
```

Since you're using a strongly typed language, this input is not really well formed. You should think about either using a different language to match your problem, or changing your input to better fit your environment.