# Generic Type JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(string)

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.JSON.  I won't know the type of object passed to this method, or retrieved to this method, so I am attempting to use `DeserializeObject` on an object I do not know the type of.

Is this possible? If so, how?
Here is my code.

```
public static List<T> GetObject<T>(string cacheKey, IEnumerable<T> obj)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:53805/api/NonPersisted/Get/" + cacheKey).Result;

        obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<obj.GetType>(response.Content.ToString());
        return obj.ToList();
    }            
}
```

I attempted first to use

`obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(response.Content.ToString());`

This didn't work, obviously, it was unable to parse.
Getting the Type of the object won't build, it says `obj is a variable but used like a type`.

**EDIT**
It appears you can use a generic `List<T>` without knowing the type with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>` The real error was that the `response.Content` was only returning the type. You need to have...

```
obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>> didn't work?

Comment: How about to use dynamic `obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);`  and then access your properties like `obj.MyCustomProperty`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I know it is always going to be a list, and no I can't cast to a type I don't know. Usually you write `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>` and it knows all the properties so it can convert to the Type `SomeObject` in my case, I can't strongly type the `List<T>`

Comment: What happens when you try to do this?

Comment: by the way, are you sure your API always return a list of objects and not a single object? I don't see a reason why DeserializeObject<List<T>> should not work in your case. Something is wrong with your json structure

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya When I try what you ask. You will always get this parsing error. It needs to know the properties to create the object. `An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

Comment: @DolceVita With your dynamic I get the same issue. `Deserialize` must still know the properties of the object. Here is the error, it's the same as ChetanRanPariyas `An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

Comment: could you please share your json response?

Comment: Side note, [you shouldn't be wrapping your HttpClient in a using statement](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).  Also just noticed the potential thread lock since you aren't awaiting the call using `async/await`

Comment: You can use a dynamic object in that case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net

Comment: @maccettura I can't ensure that the developers who would be consuming this `GetObject` method, which will be in a dll, can use async. I'm okay with locking, BUT THAT IS A GREAT READ, Who knows how many problems that has caused.

Comment: @christopherclark `HttpClient` was designed to use async/await.  If you only ever plan to call it synchronously perhaps `WebClient` is what you need?

Comment: If you share the json value string you are dealing with a better solution can be provided

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make `GetObject` method generic without having parameter `IEnumerable<T> obj`.

Following solution I am suggesting with assumption that you know the format of the JSON value being returned from the URL.

For example, that the URL returns JSON which contains array of items and each item has two properties `firstName` and `lastName`.

```
var response = "[{\"firstName\":\"Melanie\",\"lastName\":\"Acevedo\"},
    {\"firstName\":\"Rich\",\"lastName\":\"Garrett\"},
    {\"firstName\":\"Dominguez\",\"lastName\":\"Rose\"},
    {\"firstName\":\"Louisa\",\"lastName\":\"Howell\"},
    {\"firstName\":\"Stone\",\"lastName\":\"Bean\"},
    {\"firstName\":\"Karen\",\"lastName\":\"Buckley\"}]";
```

I can write `GetObject` method as following.

```
public static List<T> GetObject<T>()
{
    var response = "
        [{\"firstName\":\"Melanie\",\"lastName\":\"Acevedo\"},
        {\"firstName\":\"Rich\",\"lastName\":\"Garrett\"},
        {\"firstName\":\"Dominguez\",\"lastName\":\"Rose\"},
        {\"firstName\":\"Louisa\",\"lastName\":\"Howell\"},
        {\"firstName\":\"Stone\",\"lastName\":\"Bean\"},
        {\"firstName\":\"Karen\",\"lastName\":\"Buckley\"}]";

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(response);
        return obj.ToList();
}
```

Here `T` in above method can by any type which has properties `firstName` and `lastName`. For example

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}
```

I can call `GetObject` method by passing either `Person` or `Employee` and get the JSON string deserialize to the collection of objects of these classes as following.

```
var persons = GetObject<Person>();

foreach (var item in persons)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.FirstName} {item.LastName}");
}

var employees = GetObject<Employee>();

foreach (var item in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.FirstName} {item.LastName}");
}
```

Overall, the point I am trying to make is if format of the JSON is know the passing appropriate Type to `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>` should work without any problem.

If incoming JSON represents a collection and trying to deserialize it to a simple class would fail and vice versa too will not work.

So for your problem, if you know that JSON is going to be a collection then using `JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<T>>` should not give you any problem as long  `T` has the properties to which values from JSON can be set.

I hope this would help you resolve your issue.

Comment: I marked this as correct, because it appears you can use `JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<T>>` There was actually an error in my response Content. I will edit my answer to include the problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can call `Deserialize<T>(..)` if you do not known type T.
Only thing I can think of is getting Object:

```
    public static Object GetObject(string cacheKey)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:53805/api/NonPersisted/Get/" + cacheKey).Result;

            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ToString());
            return obj;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think this is going to be the easiest solution. It would have been easier for the developers, but one cast shouldn't kill them!

Answer (score 1):

I am not in a position where I can test this right now, but I think the following could work.  I have found that JSON.NET does not like `List<T>` when deserializing, I typically get around this by using arrays instead.

```
static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
public static async Task<T[]> GetObject<T>(string cacheKey)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient .GetAsync("http://localhost:53805/api/NonPersisted/Get/" + cacheKey);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(response.Content.ToString());
}
```

I took the liberty of removing the `using` statement for `HttpClient` and made it a static member instead.  I also changed the method to run `async`, you can change it back easily but as I mentioned in my comment you might want to avoid `HttpClient` and use [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: `response.Content.ToString()` was the problem all along. `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing the type into the function without strongly typing it.
For example:

```
Type type = obj.GetType();  
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type);
```

Comment: This returns object and not what the question wants which is a List<T>