# C# deserialize JSON using JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am not a C# programmer, but rather playing with the language from time to time. I wonder, if I have a JSON string which I want to deserialize using [JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject(v=vs.110).aspx), how could I do that. For instance, if I have a JSON:

```
{
    "Name": "col_name2",
    "Value": [
        {
            "From": 100,
            "To": 200
        },
        {
            "From": 100,
            "To": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have that JSON string in a variable called `sJson`:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
...

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Object json = jss.DeserializeObject(sJson);
```

and now how do I use this `Object json` variable?

Note: I already know how to do it using `System.Web.Script.Serialization.Deserialize<T>` method.

Comment: The result in this case will be a `Dictionary<string, object>`, where the key for one item will be  `"Name"` with a value of "`col_name2"`, another with `"Value"` with a value of `object[]`, the two objects inside the json array. You should create some classes to deserialize into, makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it works as you say, the only thing is that instead of Object json I have to use dynamic json = jss.DeserializeObject(sJson); and that was what was stopping me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at this post for Davids Answer:

[Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

You can put it into a dynamic (underlying type is JObject)
Then you can than access the information like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic json = jss.DeserializeObject(sJson);
Console.WriteLine(json["Name"]); // use as Dictionary
```

I would prefer create a data transfer object ([DTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx)) represent your JSON Structure as a c# class.

Comment: It compiles, but at run time it throw an exception: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' does not cont
ain a definition for 'Name'.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: I have to call it like that: Console.WriteLine(json["Name"]);

Answer (score 2):

You could declare new custom classes for this specific case:

```
public class CustomClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ValueClass> Value { get; set; }
}

public class ValueClass
{
    public int From { get; set; }
    public int To { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize directly to those classes (the deserializer will automatically map the correct properties):

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
CustomClass json = (CustomClass)jss.Deserialize(sJson, typeof(CustomClass));
```

Moreover if you have more than 1 items, this is easy as well:

```
List<CustomClass> json = (List<CustomClass>)jss.Deserialize(sJson, typeof(List<CustomClass>));
```