# JSON Not Deserializing certain values

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am consuming an API which returns the following JSON

```
{"coord":{"lon":-1.38,"lat":54.91},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":285.83,"pressure":1013,"humidity":76,"temp_min":285.15,"temp_max":286.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":240},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1536913200,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5104,"message":0.0049,"country":"GB","sunrise":1536903391,"sunset":1536949457},"id":2636531,"name":"Sunderland","cod":200}
```

I call the API and return the JSON as a string (strJson), from strJson I use the following code to deserialize the JSON and return the values.

```
JsonResponse res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(strJson);
```

I am able to return the items that reside within "weather" by using the following inside my JsonResponse class (I'm only returning "main" at the moment, which works successfully;

```
class JsonResponse
{

    public object coord { get; set; }
    public IList<Weather> weather { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
 class Weather
    {
    public string main { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried all sorts to return the data that resides within "coord" and "sys" but i keep getting the error "Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) to deserialize correctly".

I am able to return into into an "object" using

```
public object coord {get; set;}
```

however this isn't effective as I'm still unable to quickly extract the variables lon & Lat as well as their values.

Any help would be appreciated as I've asked a similar question before, however the answers I've found stop me from being able to extract the values from "weather" so I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
class JsonResponse
{
    public CoordObject coord {get;set;}
}

class CoordObject
{
    public double lon {get;set;}
    public double lat {get;set;}
}
```

You should then be able to access `res.coord.lon` and `res.coord.lat`.

With a quick search "*json detect class*", I found this helpful site: [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) which generated the following classes for your JSON:

```
public class Coord
{
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public int deg { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double message { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public int visibility { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Yes, it might be some times surprising, but having "nothing" deserialized (instead of an Exception) if the JSON doesn't match the correct class definition is the intended default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic for the object see here: [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

I can give a code example if you like, but there is one on the page.