# How to get token value from jsonconvert.deserializeobject

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to get the token value from a JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

```
   static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var apiClient = new ApiClient("https://connect.test.com/test/");
        var authenticate =  await Authenticate(apiClient);
        var token =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(authenticate.RawContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);    
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**Value token:**

```
    {{
  "token": "eyJraWQiOiJNSytSKzRhYUk4YjBxVkhBMkZLZFN4Ykdpb3RXbTNXOGhZWE45dXF3K3YwPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiIxYmRlZjJkNy05YTRlLTRmYmYtYTk4Zi02Y2EwNzE0NTgzNzgiLCJlbWFpb
}}
```

I've tried to split the string but thats not the clean way is there a another way to solve this ?

Comment: where you have tried to trim string ? show us code

Comment: Is that even a valid JSON response with `{{` and without a `"` at the end of the token? Please give us correct information.

Comment: You're deserializing the string to an object, because JsonConvert doesn't know the type. You can either deserialize to a `dynamic` or use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` and use a model Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the JSON you're getting (as the JSON in your question is invalid)

```
{
    "token":"eyJraWQiOiJNSytSKzRhYUk4YjBxVkhBMkZLZFN4Ykdpb3RXbTNXOGhZWE45dXF3K3YwPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiIxYmRlZjJkNy05YTRlLTRmYmYtYTk4Zi02Y2EwNzE0NTgzNzgiLCJlbWFpb"
}
```

you can 1: Deserialize it to a `dynamic` like so: (as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972079/9363973) answer)

```cs
dynamic parsed = JObject.Parse(authenticate.RawContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
Console.WriteLine(parsed.token);
```

or (my preferred typesafe way) use a model class to deserialize to like so:

```cs
class AuthenticationModel
{
    [JsonProperty("token")]
    public string Token {get; set;}
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticationModel>(await authenticate.RawContent.ReadAsStringAsync());
    Console.WriteLine(parsed.Token);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
 dynamic obj =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(authenticate.RawContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    string token = Convert.ToString(obj.token);
```