# How to use an argument with a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, json

Is it possible to pass in an argument to a dynamic object, so it returns the object required at runtime?

```
var file = File.ReadAllText("file.json");
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(file);
var value = GetValue("EnvironmentConfiguration.Environment");

private static string GetValue(string jsonKey) {

   // pass jsonKey somehow here? Something like this...
   return json.(jsonKey);
}
```

Is this even possible?

EDIT:

Json file:

```
{
  "EnvironmentConfiguration": 
  {
    "Environment": "local"
  }
}
```

Assuming we want to get the value "local" from "EnvironmentConfiguration.Environment".

Comment: Can you post you json?

Comment: There's a couple of ways to do this, depends on the JSON structure. Can you be a little more specific, perhaps share some example JSON?

Comment: Something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7wPDJi is "version" a constant value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: Added a simple json file.

Comment: @DavidG doesn't seem like it, my question is different. Want to pass in an argument to a dynamic object?

Comment: What is wrong with `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`?

Comment: @Selvin Because a dictionary doesn't cover this structure.

Comment: now it covers ... `json["EnvironmentConfiguration"]["Environment"]`

Comment: @Selvin What if it was 3 levels deep then?

Comment: also he may use "real" object structure ... having  `"EnvironmentConfiguration.Environment"` **constant string** has no added value over having `class EnvironmentConfiguration` and `class Environment` and `class X`

Comment: @Selvin Sure, but that's not the question being asked.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `JObject` and the [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) method:

```
var jobject = JObject.Parse(file);

var value = jobject
    .SelectToken("EnvironmentConfiguration.Environment")
    .ToString();
```

Comment: This is interesting, let me try this approach. Give me a sec.

Comment: This works successfully, and does solve my problem, thank you for that. However, the question still stands - can a dynamic object have an argument passed to it?

Comment: That's not really a clear question, what do you mean by "passing an argument"?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your property by using indexer:

```
return json[jsonKey];
```

Comment: jsonKey is a string, and json is resolved as a generic object type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.NET as follows:

```
dynamic json = JObject.Parse("{number:5555, str:'myString', array: [1,2,3,4,5]}");
var value1 = json.number;  // get number value -> 5555
var value2 = json.str;     // get string value -> myString
var value3 = json.array.Count;  // get array count value  -> 5
```

Comment: No, this is if you hardcode "json.number", if you were to create a method, which you didn't hardcode ".number", how would you pass it in as an argument i.e. json.(argument)? Is essentially what i'm asking.