# How can we create an anonymous object from json string in c#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, anonymous-objects

My JSON string will be like

[image]

when I deserialize it using Newtonsoft.Json, instead of object I am getting below response

[image]

But it should be like below image

[image]

tried JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and  JObject.Parse. is there any way to get in direct object structure when we deserialize it without knowing type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4535840/8395242)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: Whenever we deserialize to object/dynamic, we are getting object but it is not exactly as we create an anonymous object, it is in different structure.

Answer (score 2):

Try a dynamic? e.g.

```
dynamic thing = JObject.Parse("{Id:123, PhoneNumber: { Primary: 12345, Secondary: 78945}");

Console.WriteLine(thing.Id);
Console.WriteLine(thing.PhoneNumber);
Console.WriteLine(thing.PhoneNumber.Primary);
```