# How to parse weird JSON in go

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to parse the json below in go, but struggling to find the type or struct to decode into. I don't have any control over the format and the stocks returned might be different for each call, so I can't have a type named AAPL or TSLA. I ultimately want an array/list of objects with the data inside the 'quote' section. Something like:

```
type Stock struct {
  Symbol string
  CompanyName string
  latestPrice float64
}
```

Any thoughts?

```
{
  "AAPL": {
    "quote": {
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "companyName": "Apple, Inc.",
      "open": 308,
      "close": 315.01,
      "high": 317.05,
      "low": 307.24,
      "latestPrice": 315.01,
      "marketCap": 1365360443400,
      "peRatio": 24.49,
      "week52High": 327.85,
      "week52Low": 170.27
    }
  },
  "TSLA": {
    "quote": {
      "symbol": "TSLA",
      "companyName": "Tesla, Inc.",
      "open": 790.51,
      "close": 811.29,
      "high": 824,
      "low": 785,
      "latestPrice": 811.29,
      "marketCap": 150389638590,
      "peRatio": -963.76,
      "week52High": 968.99,
      "week52Low": 176.99
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing weird about that json. What's wrong with decoding it into the obvious structure and transforming the data afterwards?

Comment: [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4535840/8967612)

Comment: You have a `C#` and a `go` tag, you might want to remove the `C#` one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to export *all* your fields, then you can use a `map` whenever the field names are not known up front. After unmarshaling you can then range over the map and put the data to whatever other structure you would like.

```
type Stock struct {
    Symbol      string
    CompanyName string
    LatestPrice float64
}

func main() {
    var m map[string]struct{ Quote Stock }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var list []Stock
    for _, v := range m {
        list = append(list, v.Quote)
    }

    fmt.Println(list)
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/ZXlrWWWgxvB

Comment: You should probably put this logic in a custom unmarshal function.