# How to select Newtonsoft dynamic type property value?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this working code that uses Newtonsoft to deserialize a json string into a dynamic object.

```
 dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(ResultJson);
```

and then I search for a particular token to get its property name

```
var countries = json.SelectTokens("$..CountryValue");
foreach (var token in countries)
{

}
```

Using Visual Studio watch window during debugging, I can see the `token` has `{[  {    "Code": "USA"  }]}`

My question is how do I grab the property value `USA` from `token`?

Updated: I managed to extract the property value with `token[0].Code`. Problem solved.

Comment: don't include the `<dynamic>` generic argument? Or, use JObject/JArray parsing: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: It's okay. I solved already with `token[0].Code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to extract the property value with `token[0].Code`