# ExpandoObject with dynamic deserialized JSON throwing an exception when trying to access a property

Tags: c#, json, exception, dynamic, expandoobject

I have a dynamic JSON string (the structure can change depending on the content sent by the server). I'm deserializing it using `Newstonsoft.Json` as a dynamic ExpandoObject

```
dynamic jsonMeta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonScript, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

The reason I'm using a `dynamic ExpandoObject` is because it's supposed to allow me the flexibility to work with a non-fixed JSON structure.

I'm trying to access a property called (e.g. *plot*) which may or may not exist:

```
string plot = jsonMeta.plot
```

The problem I'm facing is that when `plot` does not exist in the JSON string, I'm expecting it to return a 'null' but instead it's throwing an exception:

> 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'plot' Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

How can I get it to return a `null` instead of throwing an exception when it encounters a property that doesn't exist?

I'm would prefer not trying to check for the existence of the property as it would cause extreme code bloat since my goal is to use a nested null conditional operator like `jsonMeta.plot?.name?.text`

Is it possible to override or change the ExpandoObject behavior?
If there's a cleaner way to handler this situation I'm open to considering it (not tied to ExpandoObject or Newtonsoft.Json).

EDIT: Someone marked this as a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net). It's quite different, it's not about how to deserialize an anonymous JSON, but rather about how to *not to get an exception* when accessing properties in an anonymous deserialized JSON (using ExpandoObject or any other means).

Comment: Have you consider deserialize as `dynamic` instead of `ExpandoObject`? `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonScript, new ExpandoObjectConverter());` Or alternative you should make use of `JObject`.

Comment: @YongShun `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonScript);` *already* deserialises to `JObject`. `JToken` implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, which is why it works with `dynamic`.

Comment: @YongShun if I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonScript, new ExpandoObjectConverter())` instead of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonScript, new ExpandoObjectConverter())`, then I get back a `JObject`, which I can't deference dicrectly, i.e. I can't use `jsonMeta.someProp`, I have to use `jsonMeta.someProp.Value` which makes it code even more complicated when there are many nested properties in a large JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The ExpandoObject is effectively just a dictionary.  So you can use a dictionary instead.

```
Dictionary<string,object?> jsonMeta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object?>>(jsonScript);
```

So then you can simply check for an existing key, and perform your work based on this.

```
if (jsonMeta.ContainsKey("plot"))
{
    string plot = jsonMeta["plot"] as string;
}
```

Comment: Yes am aware of that but it doesn’t solve my problem of accessing nested properties without code bloat, ie `jsonMeta?.a?.b?.c`